# What is the Xpath query and context for this?

Tags: drupal, xpath, xml-parsing

Can anyone kindly point me to the right direction to parse this iTunes feed using Drupal Xpath parser  module ?

Below is a sample of the file. Actual feed [here](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topalbums/limit=25/xml)

> http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topalbums/limit=25/xmliTunes
>   Store: Top
>   Albums2011-11-07T01:41:05-07:00http://phobos.apple.com/favicon.icoiTunes
>   Storehttp://www.apple.com/itunes/Copyright
>   2008 Apple Inc.
>                     
>                 2011-11-07T01:41:05-07:00
>
> ```
>               <id>http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/mylo-xyloto/id471339278?uo=2</id>
>
>               <title>Mylo Xyloto - Coldplay</title>
> ```

I tried this.
  Context :-   /*
  Title: feed/id/entry/title

When debugging, Context returned the entire document but Title got nothing.
It would be great if you can help me to find right xpath query.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Drupal, but considering the XPaths I'd say:

```
Title: //entry/title
Content: //entry/content
```

And so on. Is this what you were looking for?